# Disable Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Hierarchical Kendo grid, and on some condition I need to disable it, i.e disable the expand/collapse functionality, sorting, column reorder, column resizing, Any workaround for same?

Comment: Hello, could you add some code or JsFiddle to work on as example?

Comment: please add some code for the same.

Comment: for instance on edit of the grid I Have the below code:
    function onEdit(e) {
    var prepay = $('#PrePayFlag').prop('checked');
 if(prepay)
{
//here I want to disable the grid, i.e the grid should not be able to perform any operation like pagination,sorting/filtering.
}
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please add 'k-state-disabled' class for disabled thing in kendo.
so find element which you want to disable and add this class..

or

prevent event like this for the same...

```
$("#grid").find(".k-grid-header .k-link,.k-grid-pager .k-link").click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

if you like my answer then don't forget to vote me..

Comment: Thanks a lot, although k-state-disabled dosen't work but e.stopPropagation() does my work.. :)

Comment: you can add pointer events : none css to the elements .This works for me.